# Let f be twice continuously differentiable on [a, b] and three times differentiable on (a, b)

Tags: real-analysis

Let f be twice continuously differentiable on [a, b] and three times differentiable
on (a, b), with
f(a) = f(b) = 0, f'
(a+) = f
'
(b−) > 0, f'''(x) > 0, x ∈ (a, b). (∗)
(i) Show that there is a point c ∈ (a, b) such that f
''(x) < 0 for all x ∈ [a, c) and
f
''(x) > 0 for all x ∈ (c, b]. 
(ii) Deduce that f
' has a strict minimum at c, and that at this point f
'
(c) < 0.
(iii) Deduce that f has a positive maximum in (a, c) and a negative minimum in (c, b).
(iv) With [a, b] = [−1, 1] find an example of a function that satisfies the conditions in (∗)

I am basically stuck on how to do any of this. I want to use Rolle's theorem in the first part (and maybe other parts) but i'm not sure how it helps. All it gives is that there exists a c ∈ (a, b) s.t f'(c)=0 and i'm not sure how to use this.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Answer (score 1):

The fact that $f''' > 0$ on $(a,b)$ means that $f''$ is strictly increasing on that interval. To verify part (i) it suffices to show that $f''(x) < 0$ for at least one $x$ and $f''(y) > 0$ for at least one $y$.

Apply the mean value theorem. Since $f(a) = f(b) = 0$ there exists a point $c \in (a,b)$ with $f'(c) = 0$. This means there exist points $a < x < c$ and $c < y < b$ satisfying 
$$f''(x) = \frac{f'(c) - f'(a)}{c-a} < 0$$ and $$f''(y) = \frac{f'(b) - f'(c)}{b - c} > 0.$$

The remaining parts should follow from (i) without much difficulty.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help but I'm not sure how parts ii and iii follow from i. A little more help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Since $f''$ is strictly increasing and $f''(c) = 0$ you must have $f''< 0$ on $[a,c)$.  Similarly $f'' > 0$ on $(c,b]$. This means $f'$ is strictly decreasing on $[a,c)$ and strictly increasing on $(c,b]$. This forces $f'$ to have a strict minimum at $c$. This is just the first derivative test applied to $f'$.